# fourth-order finite difference for $(a(x)u'(x))'$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, finite-differences, numerical-calculus, finite-difference-methods

Previously I asked [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/41306/constructing-a-symmetric-matrix-for-finite-difference?noredirect=1#comment80362_41306) about constructing a symmetric matrix for doing finite difference for $(a(x)u'(x))'$ where the (diffusion) coefficient $a(x)$ is spatially varying. The answer provided there works for getting a second order accurate method. What about getting a fourth-order accurate method? If I follow the same idea and apply the following fourth-order accurate formula for first derivative

$ u'_i = \dfrac{u_{i-1} - 8u_{i-1/2} + 8u_{i+1/2} - u_{i+1}}{6\Delta x}$   (1)

in succession, then I end up getting a formula for $(a u')_i'$ which involves $u_{i-2}, u_{i-3/2}, u_{i-1}, u_{i-1/2}, u_i, u_{i+1/2}, u_{i+1}, u_{i+3/2}, u_2$. It involves the mid point values $u_{i+n/2}$ and it depends on nine neighbouring values of $u_i$, which doesn't sound right for fourth order accurate scheme. For the special case of $a(x)=1$ it also doesn't reduce to the formula

$ u'' = \dfrac{-u_{i-2} + 16u_{i-1} - 30u_i + 16u_{i+1} - u_{i+2}}{12\Delta x^2}$.   (2)

So what's wrong with applying (1) in succession? What's the correct approach to get a finite difference formula for $(au')'$ with fourth order accuracy?

Edit 1: After reading this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756717/finite-differences-second-derivative-as-successive-application-of-the-first-deri) I managed to derive a symmetric four-order centered difference scheme for $[a(x)u'(x)]'$ by applying

$ u'(x) = \dfrac{u_{i-3/2} - 27u_{i-1/2} + 27u_{i+1/2} - u_{i+3/2}}{24\Delta x} + \mathcal{O}(\Delta x^4)$

twice in succession. The resulting formula for $[a(x)u'(x)]'$ is

$ (au')'_i = \dfrac{1}{576\Delta x^2} \left( a_{i-\frac{3}{2}}u_{i-3}
- 27(a_{i-\frac{3}{2}} + a_{i-\frac{1}{2}})u_{i-2}
+ (27a_{i-\frac{3}{2}} + 729a_{i-\frac{1}{2}}+27a_{i+\frac{1}{2}})u_{i-1}
- (a_{i-\frac{3}{2}} + 729a_{i-\frac{1}{2}} + 729a_{i+\frac{1}{2}} + a_{i+\frac{3}{2}})u_i
+ (27a_{i-\frac{1}{2}} + 729a_{i+\frac{1}{2}}+27a_{i+\frac{3}{2}})u_{i+1}
- 27(a_{i+\frac{1}{2}} + a_{i+\frac{3}{2}})u_{i+2}
+ a_{i+\frac{3}{2}}u_{i+3} \right)$

which involves the mid point values of $a(x)$ and has seven stencils. Is there a formula that involves even less computations / stencils(e.g. five stencils)?

Answer (score 2):

Let's use
$$
f'(x) = \frac{f_{i-3/2} - 27 f_{i-1/2} + 27 f_{i+1/2} - f_{i+3/2}}{24 \Delta x} + O(\Delta x^4)
$$
as an approximation for the outer derivative. To obtain a fourth-order approximation for the $(au_x)_x$ term we need to obtain $a u_x$ at each of the $x_{i-3/2}, x_{i-1/2}, x_{i+1/2}, x_{i+3/2}$ points with fourth-order accuracy.

Assuming that we know $a$ everywhere, the problem reduces to computing $u_x$ at those points. Taking our stencil to be $(x_{i-2}, x_{i-1}, x_{i}, x_{i+1}, x_{i+2})$ we can compute fourth degree interpolating polynomial $P(x)$ for $u(x)$:
$$u(x) = P(x) + O(\Delta x^5).$$
Differentiating that polynomial gives fourth-order approximation for $u_x$:
$$
u_x(x) = P'(x) + O(\Delta x^4).
$$

Omitting straightforward computations (which I've done using *Mathics*) we get the following approximations for $u_x(x_{i-3/2}), \dots, u_x(x_{i+3/2})$
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
u_x(x_{i-3/2})\\
u_x(x_{i-1/2})\\
u_x(x_{i+1/2})\\
u_x(x_{i+3/2})
\end{pmatrix}
= 
\frac{1}{24 \Delta x}
\begin{pmatrix}
 -22 & 17 & 9 & -5 & 1\\ 
1 & -27 & 27 & -1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & -27 & 27 & -1\\
 -1 & 5 & -9 & -17 & 22
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
u_{i-2}\\
u_{i+1}\\
u_{i}\\
u_{i+1}\\
u_{i+2}
\end{pmatrix}
+ O(\Delta x^4).
$$

Combining everything to a single formula we get
$$
(a u_x)_x = \frac{1}{24 \Delta x} \times \left[\\
a_{i-3/2} \frac{u_{i+2} - 5 u_{i+1} + 9 u_i + 17 u_{i-1} - 22 u_{i-2}}{24 \Delta x}
-27a_{i-1/2} \frac{-u_{i+1} + 27 u_i - 27 u_{i-1} + u_{i-2}}{24 \Delta x} +\\
+27a_{i+1/2} \frac{-u_{i+2} + 27 u_{i+1} - 27 u_{i} + u_{i-1}}{24 \Delta x} -a_{i+3/2} \frac{22u_{i+2} - 17 u_{i+1} - 9 u_i + 5 u_{i-1} - u_{i-2}}{24 \Delta x}\\
\right] + O(\Delta x^4).
$$

Comment: I have checked the above formula in Mathematica and it does give a fourth-order approximation to $(a(x)u'(x))'$, but the resulting finite difference matrix is not symmetric. Is there a similar way to construct a symmetric matrix?

Comment: FDM has no intrinsic structure that can guarantee matrix symmetry. If you really require it, use FEM. Usually you get an additional matrix, but everything will be symmetric and compact for arbitrary order.

I tried to discretize a weak formulation of the derivative $\langle (a u_x)_x, \psi \rangle = -\langle a u_x, \psi_x \rangle$ (this expression is symmetric), but it results in the same 7 point approximation.

Answer (score 2):

A bit of work with five-point Lagrange interpolants based on a uniform grid for $a$ and $u$ shows, with
\begin{align}
w_{-2} &:= \tfrac{1}{144}a_{-2} - \tfrac{1}{18} a_{-1} - \tfrac{1}{12}a_0 + \tfrac{1}{18} a_1 - \tfrac{1}{144} a_2, \\
w_{-1} &:= -\tfrac{1}{18}a_{-2} + \tfrac{4}{9} a_{-1} + \tfrac{4}{3} a_0 - \tfrac{4}{9}a_1 + \tfrac{1}{18}a_2 \\
w_0 &:= -\tfrac{5}{2}a_0, \\
w_{1} &:= \tfrac{1}{18}a_{-2} - \tfrac{4}{9}a_{-1} + \tfrac{4}{3}a_0 + \tfrac{4}{9}a_1 - \tfrac{1}{18}a_2, \\
w_{2} &:= -\tfrac{1}{144}a_{-2} + \tfrac{1}{18}a_{-1} - \tfrac{1}{12}a_0 - \tfrac{1}{18}a_1 + \tfrac{1}{144}a_2
\end{align}
that $(au')'(0) = (w_{-2}u_{-2}+ w_{-1}u_{-1} + w_0u_0 + w_1 u_1 + w_2 u_2)/h^2 + O(h^4)$. It typically won't be a symmetric rule.

ADDED EDIT

Since I was thinking in terms of using grid values I started with the Lagrange interpolant for $a$
\begin{align*}
        A(x) &= \\
        & \quad a_{-2}\,
\frac{x - x_{-1}}{x_{-2} - x_{-1}}
\frac{x - x_{0}}{x_{-2} - x_{0}}
\frac{x - x_{1}}{x_{-2} - x_{1}}
\frac{x - x_{2}}{x_{-2} - x_{2}} \\
        &+  a_{-1}\,
\frac{x - x_{-2}}{x_{-1} - x_{-2}}
\frac{x - x_{0}}{x_{-1} - x_{0}}
\frac{x - x_{1}}{x_{-1} - x_{1}}
\frac{x - x_{2}}{x_{-1} - x_{2}} \\
        &+ a_{0}\,
\frac{x - x_{-2}}{x_{0} - x_{-2}}
\frac{x - x_{-1}}{x_{0} - x_{-1}}
\frac{x - x_{1}}{x_{0} - x_{1}}
\frac{x - x_{2}}{x_{0} - x_{2}} \\
        &+ a_{1}\,
\frac{x - x_{-2}}{x_{1} - x_{-2}}
\frac{x - x_{-1}}{x_{1} - x_{-1}}
\frac{x - x_{0}}{x_{1} - x_{0}}
\frac{x - x_{2}}{x_{1} - x_{2}} \\
        &+ a_{2}\,
\frac{x - x_{-2}}{x_{2} - x_{-2}}
\frac{x - x_{-1}}{x_{2} - x_{-1}}
\frac{x - x_{0}}{x_{2} - x_{0}}
\frac{x - x_{1}}{x_{2} - x_{1}}
\end{align*}
and the corresponding $U$ for $u$. Setting $x_{k} = kh$ for a uniform mesh simplifies the expressions and makes the template symmetric about $x=0$. Computing $(AU')'$ and evaluating it at $x=0$ gives the result which can be verified to be $O(h^4)$. The symmetric template is key.

Comment: do you mind explaining how it is derived very briefly? I know very roughly how it works when $a(x)$ is a constant but not too sure how it is modified for variable $a(x)$.

Comment: @Physicist, my pleasure adding a bit more info. I hope it helps, and best of luck to you.