# Graph being a parabola

Tags: polynomials

> Determine the polynomial $P\in \mathbb{R}[x]$ for which there exists $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ such that for all $x\in \mathbb{Q}$ we have: $$P\left(x+\frac1n\right)+P\left(x-\frac1n\right)=2P(x)$$

---

The solution given in the book says: If there is such a polynomial of degree $m ≥ 2$,differentiating the given relation $m−2$ times we find that there is a quadratic polynomial that satisfies the given relation. But then any point on its graph would be the vertex of the parabola, **which of course is impossible**. Hence only linear and constant polynomials satisfy the given relation.
**My doubt:** Why do they say that the graph can't be a parabola? They didn't provide any information about it

Answer (score 1):

Intuitive explanation : $$P\left(x+\frac1n\right)+P\left(x-\frac1n\right)-2P(x)=0$$

can be read as "second (discrete) derivative" is $0$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3756717/305862) for example). Therefore, no wonder that it is only first degree polynomials that are solutions.

Answer (score -1):

If $P(x)=ax^2+bx+c$, then
$$
0=2P(x)-\left(P\left(x+\frac1n\right)+P\left(x-\frac1n\right)\right)=-\frac{2a}{n^2},
$$
and therefore $a=0$.